# SQL Server for finding next European Summer Time date

Tags: sql-server, date, timezone, dst

I have one table in SQL Server where I want to add a column that will show this year's date for the exact transition dates for European Summer Time.

> European Summer Time is observed across three time zones, beginning at 01:00 UTC/WET on the last Sunday in March and ending at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in October each year.

How do you change this into a SQL function?

On Wikipedia I was able to find this:

The formula used to calculate the beginning of European Summer Time is
Sunday (31 − ((((5 × y) ÷ 4) + 4) mod 7)) March at 01:00 UTC
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe

Comment: What is your table schema? Why are you after this information? Why do you want to store it?

Comment: In this table I store names for a lot of cities. I am going to show the winter time difference and summer time difference from UTC time. Is it UTC+2 or +3 hours for this city compared to UTC. 
And want also to show when the time will change from summer time to winter time as I would like to highlight that on an internal website. –

Comment: Don't use your own database for that. Just use the system timezone database and expose that to your users, that way it will always be kept up-to-date.

Comment: I think just by converting this formula from Wikipedia into sql syntax will fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. DST is a non-technical, but political policy and can vary over time (countries change DST adjustments all the time) which requires an up-to-date timezone database.

SQL Server itself is not concerned with timezones: it does not perform any timezone conversion itself, only UTF-offset conversion (when using `datetimeoffset` when the instantaneous local-to-UTC conversion is known). It cannot tell you anything about zone locations or future offsets, as those are arguably business rules that belong outside the domain of the persistence layer (i.e. SQL Server). When storing values in a database always used either UTC `datetime` or `datetimeoffset` values. Use UTC `datetime` when zone information is irrelevant to the user (i.e. don't invent your own `datetime+int` system, use `datetimeoffset`).

Along those lines, SQL Server does not provide any API or functionality for accessing the system (the Windows OS') timezone database from T-SQL code.

You would need to do this from application code. In .NET you can use the `TimeZoneInfo` class which uses Windows' timezone database to get the DST dates:

```
TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateStart
TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateEnd
TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart
TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is mostly true, however SQL Server 2016 now has `AT TIME ZONE` - as of CTP 3.1.  [See announcement](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/11/30/sql-server-2016-community-technology-preview-3-1-is-available.aspx) and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx).  Still, it only helps with conversions, not with determining the transition dates.

Comment: @MattJohnson As a purist, this new functionality offends me :)

Comment: It becomes important for SSRS, data warehousing, etc. For OLTP, I agree that it's better to do this stuff in the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the criteria you're inputting into whatever function you want to produce here is, the specific code is going to be different.

The following, for example, produces a list of the dates/times for the next 100 years in the timezone this is run in.

```
; WITH C1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) T(N))
, C2(N, RN) AS (SELECT 1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) FROM C1 a CROSS JOIN C1 b)
, TYears AS (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) + RN - 1 [Years] FROM C2)
SELECT DATEADD(hh
        , DATEDIFF(hh, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
        , DATEADD(dd
            , 0 - (1 + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Years]) + '-03-31')) % 7) % 7
            , CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Years]) + '-03-31 01:00:00'))) [StartDateTime]
    , DATEADD(hh
        , DATEDIFF(hh, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
        , DATEADD(dd
            , 0 - (1 + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Years]) + '-10-31')) % 7) % 7
            , CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Years]) + '-10-31 01:00:00'))) [EndDateTime]
FROM TYears
```

The basic premise being find the last Sunday of March for that year, find the UTC +/- value, add it to 1AM of the last Sunday of March.